# Netoffice Outlook addin registration trouble

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, netoffice

I'm trying to register a Netoffice Outlook Addin. After creating it with the Netoffice Developer Toolbox I am unable to start it. 
The error in visual studio is: assembly cannot be registered - access denied. Make sure that you run the application as administrator. Access to the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyAddin.Addin registry key is denied. 
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your assembly must be registered in COM for your addin to work. By default, Visual Studio will use `regasm.exe` to register the assembly.

Because regasm needs write persmissions to system registry, use mus run Visual Studio with elevated permissions (right click > Run as Administrator).

Registration must be done just once and your can do it manually from command line as well.

Addin can be also registered in user registry with the need for asministrator rights, but you must create your own script as this is not possible with regasm.exe.